# Compare an xml file elements under a tag with a CSV file and add missing elements in CSV using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file having the below elements in my tags Branch and Office- 

  
   office 1
   office 2
   office 3
   office 6
   office 4
   office 5

Other CSV file having

Offices as the Column name:
Office1
office2

I want all the missing offices to be included in the CSV file under offices using powershell.

Can anyone suggest ?

Comment: Two pointers: You can import `.csv` files with `import-csv` and xml files with `[xml](Get-Content C:\yourFile.xml)`. As for the logic, please try to come up with something yourself and we will help you fill the holes. Also take a look at [ask] and try to offer a [mcve] of your own code.

Comment: I have my CSV already imported and also have my xml in readable format. I just want to implement the logic of the above question. I am struck at this point in a bigger module.

Comment: Please show us the code you allready wrote by editing your question and try to show us the logic you allready tried.